# SmartCard Driver problems for Mac OS Mojave 10.14.6

Tags: bash, macos, driver, smartcard, libusb

I have tried a few different devices to authenticate with a CompanyCard (id Bridge), last attempt I bought the ACR39U-N1 PocketMate II Smart Card Reader.

Information:
Mac OS Mojave 10.14.6
Drivers downloaded from https://www.acs.com.hk/en/driver/426/acr39u-n1-pocketmate-ii-smart-card-reader-usb-type-a/ for the mac (rebooted after installation)

When plugging in the device, I get the following error in the system-log:

```
com.apple.ifdreader[204]: 00020998 commands.c:254:CmdPowerOn Card absent or mute-mbp com.apple.ifdreader[204]: 00023483 commands.c:254:CmdPowerOn Card absent or mute
com.apple.ifdreader[204]: 00023458 commands.c:254:CmdPowerOn Card absent or mute
com.apple.ifdreader[204]: 00023564 commands.c:254:CmdPowerOn Card absent or mute
com.apple.ifdreader[204]: 00023413 commands.c:254:CmdPowerOn Card absent or mute
com.apple.ifdreader[204]: 00023403 commands.c:254:CmdPowerOn Card absent or mute
com.apple.ifdreader[204]: 00000066 ifdhandler.c:1517:IFDHPowerICC() PowerUp failed
```

When I unplug the device I see;

```
07184046 ccid_usb.c:2480:CardDetectionThread() 20/20: Error: -99
com.apple.ifdreader[204]: 00000351 ccid_usb.c:1196:WriteUSB() write failed (20/20): -4 LIBUSB_ERROR_NO_DEVICE
kcm[6846]: DEPRECATED USE in libdispatch client: Setting timer interval to 0 requests a 1ns timer, did you mean FOREVER (a one-shot timer)?; set a breakpoint on _dispatch_bug_deprecated to debug
```

Thanks